# Error on APK Build suspicious method call

Tags: java, android, apk, lint

Trying to generate a signed APK, but I got this message :

> Error:Error: Suspicious method call; should probably call "layout"
>   rather than "onLayout" [WrongCall]

I add the SupressLint on the method, but it's not working :

```
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: like that ?  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @TargetApi(19)
 @Override
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
  mLayoutHeight = getHeight();
  mLayoutWidth = getWidth();
 }

Comment: mmmh it's not working. The issue has been reported in the github of the library https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview/issues/33
For now, I think I will set   
lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
thank you for helping

Comment: yesssssss..set this in your `build.gradle` section . I forgot this .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With Android Studio, you can also run lint inspections for a specific
>   build variant, or for all build variants from the build.gradle file.
>   Add the lintOptions property to the android settings in the build
>   file. This code snippet from a Gradle build file shows how to set the
>   quiet option to true and the abortOnError option to false.

```
android {
    lintOptions {
       // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
       quiet true
       // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
       abortOnError false
       // if true, only report errors
       ignoreWarnings true
       }
       ...
    }
```

Courtesy goes to **[Improving Your Code with lint](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Not a good solution, but if you need to generated the APK, add this in your build.gradle:

```
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

Comment: `android {
   lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
   }
}`